# I get different function behavior when using F8 or F5 key

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I created a specific function to format my charts. The main Sub and the Function code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim mychart         As Chart
Dim ChartData       As Range
Dim ChartName       As String
Dim thiswb          As Workbook
Dim imageName       As String
Dim nColunas        As Long
Dim i, j, k         As Integer

Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

k = 0

With thiswb.Sheets(4)
   MultiPage1.Pages.Add
   MultiPage1.Pages(k - 1).Controls.Copy
   MultiPage1.Pages(k).Paste
   Set ChartData = .Range("B2:B97")
   Set mychart = .Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart
     For j = mychart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
        If j = 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If
        mychart.SeriesCollection(j).Delete
     Next j
   mychart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartData
   mychart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(97, 1))

   formatchart mychart

   With .Shapes(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
     .MinimumScale = 0
     .MaximumScale = 1
   End With
   imageName = Application.DefaultFilePath & Application.PathSeparator & "GraficoTemp.gif"
   mychart.Export Filename:=imageName, FilterName:="GIF"
   .Shapes(1).Delete
   UserForm2.MultiPage1.Pages(k).Caption = "Total"
   UserForm2.Controls("Image" & k + 1).Picture = LoadPicture(imageName)

   Kill imageName

   With Controls("Listbox" & k + 1)
     .RowSource = "Total!B2:B97"
   End With
End With
End Sub

Function formatchart(mychart As Chart)
 With mychart
    .HasTitle = False
    .Legend.LegendEntries(1).Delete
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Caption = "Horas"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Potência (W)"
 End With
 With mychart.Parent
    .Height = 295 
    .Width = 470 
    .Top = 100    
    .Left = 100  
 End With
End Function
```

As you can see, the first thing the "formatchart" function does is remove the chart title. What happens is, when I run the complete Sub by pressing F5, the title is not removed. But when I debug it by pressing F8, I follow all the steps of the Sub till the end and the title ends up being removed!

What could be happening?

Comment: How are you able to call / run a function which requires a parameter by pressing F5? This shouldn't be possible unless you call it from the direct window (not using F5). Is the code on a sheet or in a module?

Comment: @Ralph The "formatchart" function is in a module and I have a main procedure where I call this function. I didn't write the whole procedure here because I didn't think it was relevant. It's only when I get to this function that the problems start.

Comment: The code calling the function should be included since I believe that your problem might be related to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940387/excel-referencing-a-chart-as-chartobjects-chart-vs-shapes

Comment: @Ralph I updated my original post to include the full code. I followed the link you referenced and tried replacing ChartObjects with Shapes, but it still doesn't work. It's really strange. I always thought debugging with F8 or running with F5 would produce the exact same result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having reconstructed the scenario on my computer with the complete code the following two things made your code work for me:

(1) Change the function into a sub and
(2) pass the `ChartObject` to the sub instead of `Chart`.

So, following this you'll have to

```
Dim mychart as ChartObject
```

and the initial setup will slightly change to

```
   Set mychart = .ChartObjects.Add(295, 470, 100, 100)
   mychart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
```

Instead of

```
formatchart mychart
```

you'll have to call the procedure like so

```
Call formatchart(mychart)
```

while changing the function to a procedure

```
Sub formatchart(mychart As ChartObject)

With mychart.Chart
   .HasTitle = False
   .Legend.LegendEntries(1).Delete
   .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
   .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Caption = "Horas"
   .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
   .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Potência (W)"
End With

With mychart
   .Height = 295
   .Width = 470
   .Top = 100
   .Left = 100
End With

End Sub
```

I believe the problem is that you are adding a `Chart` according to your variable declaration but a `Shape` when looking at your original code above:

```
Set mychart = .Shapes.AddChart(xlXYScatterLines).Chart
```

I am not sure yet why the function didn't work and had to be a procedure instead. So, since I don't fully comprehend the problem yet I can only offer what seems to work here. If this doesn't help then let's hope that someone else comes up with a more conclusive solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to analyze this issue! I did everything you said but, when the code reaches `mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartData`, I get a "Run-time error '1004': Invalid Parameter". What could be happening?

EDIT: I just did a "MsgBox ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count" and it returns zero.

Comment: There is no such thing as '.SeriesCollection(1).Values'. Try `mychart.Chart.SetSourceData = .Range("B2:B97")` instead as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678237/vba-excel-chart-seriescollection

Comment: I just removed the equals sign from the code you wrote and it seemed to work, although, the X and Y axis are now reversed and I'm getting a "Method 'MinimumScale' of object 'Axis' failed". This MinimumScale setting was for the X axis, which is supposed to have numbers in the time format.

Comment: That's because you keep mixing up `charts`, `shapes`, and `charobjects` and don't even bother to read in the VBE help file. There is no such thing as `.Shapes(1).Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0`. It should be `mychart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0` using the ChartObject and not the Chart. Please resolve the rest of these bugs by reading in the VBE help file or at least recording any changes and have a look at the recorded VBA code.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. You were really helpful!