# VBA : Getting an error for my code "Runtime error 424"

Tags: excel, vba

My code is working fine but it ends up giving me a runtime error "object required.

I am not able to find out what is causing this error. This code is related to deleting graphs that don't have any data in them .

```
Sub HideEmptyCharts()
    Dim wksCharts As Worksheet
    Dim objCO As ChartObject

    ' Set up a variable for the worksheet containing the charts
    Set wksCharts = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report output")

    ' Loop through every embedded chart object on the worksheet
    For Each objCO In wksCharts.ChartObjects
        ' Make each one visible
        objCO.Visible = True

        ' If the chart is empty make it not visible
        If IsChartEmpty(objCO.Chart) Then objCO.Visible = False
    Next objCO
End Sub

Private Function IsChartEmpty(chtAnalyse As Chart) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim objSeries As Series

    ' Loop through all series of data within the chart
    For i = 1 To chtAnalyse.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set objSeries = chtAnalyse.SeriesCollection(i)

        ' Loop through each value of the series
        For j = 1 To UBound(objSeries.Values)
            ' If we have a non-zero value then the chart is not deemed to be empty
            If objSeries.Values(j) <> 0 Then
                ' Set return value and quit function
                IsChartEmpty = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    IsChartEmpty = True
End Function
```

[image: error image]

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: not sure i cant really figure that out :(

Comment: Rephrasing @nicomp's question, ,what line throws the error if you hit `Debug`?

Comment: @jijoy thomas, I have tried your code and works fine without error...

Comment: it only gives a pop up message of "object not found" it doesnt throw any line on which the error is there even after clicking on debug

Comment: please check the image .... @ferdinando

Comment: @jijoy thomas, It is very strange... try to delete option explicit and try it...it is only this one difference from the code that i tested and your image

Comment: @Ferdinando You never want to delete `Option Explicit`. Nevertheless it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: still the same removed the open explicit still gives me the same error

Comment: It is only to try it...

Comment: @jijoythomas Go through your code step by step using F8. This way you figure out which line throws the error.

Comment: @jijoy thomas keep us updated..you tried as suggested by @Peh?

Comment: I tried f8... It didn't work ...doesn't show errors on any line

Comment: @jijoythomas Just to be clear: your whole code runs correctly if you go through it step by step pressing F8 in each step? But If you run it with F5 it throws that error?

Comment: Yes exactly @peh I did multiple checks in debug as well

Comment: @jijoythomas after Your last comment i found this post that can help you...keep US updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882850/i-get-different-function-behavior-when-using-f8-or-f5-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the object passed to the function from `Chart` to full `ChartObject`like this:

```
Private Sub HideEmptyCharts()
    Dim wksCharts As Worksheet
    Dim objCO As ChartObject

    Set wksCharts= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report output")
    For Each objCO In wksCharts.ChartObjects
        objCO.Visible = True
        If IsChartEmpty(objCO) Then objCO.Visible = False
    Next objCO
End Sub


Private Function IsChartEmpty(co As ChartObject) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim objSeries As Series
    For i = 1 To co.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set objSeries = co.Chart.SeriesCollection(i)
        For j = 1 To UBound(objSeries.Values)
            If objSeries.Values(j) <> 0 Then
                IsChartEmpty = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    IsChartEmpty = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

An outdated pivotcache and some still remembered but in the meantime missed items caused some trouble to me in the past. So I propose to add this code once before:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache
For Each pc In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
    pc.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    pc.Refresh
Next pc
```